# How do you make hierarchical class names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby a class named Foo would be defined with `class Foo`, used via `require 'foo'` and would live in `$:[0]/foo.rb` or something like that.

But what about `Foo::Bar`? Would it be called with `require 'foo/bar'`? Would it live in `$:[0]/foo/bar.rb`? And how would it be defined?

I am very used to Perl, where for personal projects I would make nested classes like `Project::User`, `Project::Text::Index`, `Project::Text::Search`, etc. I would then make a file like `Project/Text/Index.pm`, which would start with `package Project::Text::Index`, and be called via `use Project::Text::Index;`.

Now I'm starting a project in Ruby and have no idea how to do this. For some reason none of the Ruby books or docs I've read mention perl-style hierarchical class naming. When they mention inheritance it's usually via a trivial made up example like `class Foo < Bar` which doesn't really help me. Yet I figure it must be possible to do what I'm attempting because Rails (just to take one example) has classes like `ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelFormBuilder`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're combining a couple of concepts here which aren't really related, namely the load path, inheritance, and the scope resolution operator.

When requiring (or loading) files the argument to the `require` keyword is simply taken as a file path and appended to the load search path (the `.rb` extension is optional for `require`).  Inheritance and nesting don't come into play here and any file can define anything it wants, e.g.:

```
require 'foo' # Looks for "foo.rb" in each of $:
require 'foo/bar' # Looks for "foo/bar.rb" in each of $:
```

Nested classes (and modules, variables, etc) are defined as expected but resolved with the scope resolution operator, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  def foo; 'foo'; end
  class Bar
    def bar; 'bar'; end
  end
end
Foo.new.foo # => "foo"
Foo::Bar.new.bar # => "bar"
```

Note that class nesting and inheritance are irrelevant to the location of the file from which they are loaded.  There don't seem to be any explicit conventions for class/module structuring, so you're free to do what works for you.  The [Ruby Language](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html) page of the Programming Ruby book might be helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

You need modules. If you want a class identified by `Funthing::Text::Index` in `Funthing/Text/Index.rb` and be required with `require 'Funthing/Text/Index'`, you do this:

```
# file Funthing/Text/Index.rb
module Funthing
  module Text
    class Index
      def do_the_twist()
        puts "Let's twist again!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
require "Funthing/Text/Index"
c = Funthing::Text::Index.new
```

*Note: the file hierarchy is **not** required, but (in my opinion) is best practice.*

Comment: Good answer, but filenames (and require) should be downcase: funthing/text/index.rb.

Comment: Any comments on the difference between nesting a class inside modules, and nesting inside classes? It seems this module example could be given with only class definitions.